# jQuery/Javascript - how to detect that image was re-loaded

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a several actions that can be taken on the screen that would cause image to be re-loaded via Ajax call (non-jQuery). I need a way to detect that image has been reloaded so that I can attach event handler to the image again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative way of doing it is to use the [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) event in jQuery.

Which binds handlers to currently existing (selected) elements and any others which may appear later on (through a XMLHttpRequest or simply DOM handling). This means you don't have to detect if an image or other element has been reloaded, it binds the events for you automatically.

Comment: And for events not currently supported with live, there's a jQuery plugin called liveQuery that can handle all browser events in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me whether the ajax is simply updating the `src` of an image, or whether you have whole new chunks of html with `<img>` tags in them.

In any case, this should bind an `onload` event to any image on the page and any img that gets added to the DOM.

```
$('img').live("load", function(e){
  // fires when an img tag has an onload event fire.
});
```